# How to decouple MediatR from my business layer

Tags: .net-core, mediatr

Good morning.

I'm using domain events in my project, and the easiest way i found to implement it was by using MediatR.
But i don't want my project to directly depend on it, i want apply dependency inversion to hide the library.

Current code that has a dependency in Mediator, because of INotification interface

```
public class EmailConfirmedEvent : INotification
{
    public Guid PassengerId { get; }
    public string Email { get; }

    public EmailConfirmedEvent(Guid passengerId, string email)
    {
        Email = email;
        PassengerId = passengerId;
    }
}
```

But i want to be like this:

```
public class EmailConfirmedEvent : IMyProjectDomainEvent
{
    public Guid PassengerId { get; }
    public string Email { get; }

    public EmailConfirmedEvent(Guid passengerId, string email)
    {
        Email = email;
        PassengerId = passengerId;
    }
}
```

By some way i'll need to "convert" from mediator events/event handlers to my project events/event handlers.

What's the best way to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would end up having to create your own version of MediatR. which is a lot of effort. Is the trade off worth it?

Comment: Well, i'm considering a future that i'll end up switching libraries. I don't want to recreate an event dispatching library, i just want to abstract away MediatR from my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up creating my domain event custom code using StructureMap and reflection to resolve the event handlers at runtime.
Code sample here: https://github.com/Henry-Keys/domain-events-sample

Comment: This helps to "abstract the abstraction" of Mediatr. I need to do the same thing using .NET Core's built in `IServiceProvider` with Lamar underneath.

Comment: Your Github's link is broken. Could you update it ou place your code here?

Answer (score 2):

I generally make base classes that inherit from MediatR interfaces/base.  Then if you change libraries (unlikely) you just have to update the base classes and the rest of the implement remains untouched.

Comment: That's a great ideia pal, i'll put into consideration. Thanks.

Comment: I used another approach pal, sorry for the late answer